# Changing an arrays elements with thread

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I need the change the elements of an array by using a thread. It should change (add or sub an integer number) an element randomly, sleep for 2 sec and change another one randomly.

So i created my array and my thread, but I don't know how to change it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] myarray= new int[5]; 
    Thread x= new Thread();
    x.start(); 

    try 
        {
            x.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

}

}
public class myThread implements Runnable {
   public myThread(){ //an empty constructor, to pass parameters

   }
    public void run(){

    }
    public void update(){ //i tohught i could use that for changing elements

    }
```

Comment: *Unrelated:* `x.sleep(2000)` is bad code. Method `sleep` is `static`, so should be called by qualifying with the class name, not with an instance value, so it should be `Thread.sleep(2000)`

Comment: You need to pass the array into the thread as a parameter to the constructor. Also, you need to actually *use* the `myThread` class. Note that Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter, so it should be called `MyThread`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create an class declaration, that accepts required `arr` and implements `run()` method with logic.

```
public static class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private final int[] arr;
    private final Random random = new Random();

    private MyThread(int[] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // wait for 2 seconds
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
                // randomly choose array element
                int i = random.nextInt(arr.length);
                // randomly choose increment or decrement an elements
                boolean add = random.nextBoolean();

                // lock WHOLE array for modification
                synchronized (arr) {
                    arr[i] = add ? arr[i] + 1 : arr[i] - 1;
                }
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Second, you have to create an array and required number of threads for modifications.

```
// create an array
int[] arr = new int[5];

// create threads and start
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    new Thread(new MyThread(arr)).start();
```

That's all basically. Sure, it is possible to not lock whole array to modify only one elements, but this is another story.

Comment: The final `println(...)` call in your main routine can be executed while worker threads still are running. Not that anybody would be able to tell by examining the program's output, but still... Are you sure that's what you wanted to show?

Comment: I dont understand why output is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]